# Is this a bug in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have found a very peculiar behaviour with Tkinter widget focusing behaviour. Take the below code for example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Test(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        # Create Canvas
        canvas_width = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        canvas_height = master.winfo_screenheight()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
        self.canvas.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
frame = Test(root)
frame.pack()

while True:
    frame.focus_set()
    print(root.focus_get())
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
```

The `print(root.focus_get())` on the third last line outputs `.` on every interation of the loop, which is odd. You'd expect it to output something like `.!frame`. It gets weirder, since if you change the height of the canvas to `height=500` as such:

`self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=500)`

It works perfectly fine and outputs `.!frame`. I continued to experiment with this, and I found that setting `height=1176` and below works fine, but all values `height=1177` and above end up in the output becoming `.`. I suspect that this has something to do with my resolution, but no matter how high I set the width, it never raises an issue like it does when I raise the height. My resolution is `1920x1200` just in case it matters. Any thoughts on this weird behaviour?

Comment: Your Canvas is a sibling of the Frame (both children of the root window), rather than a child of it.  If you don't reduce the height of the Canvas somewhat, it pushes the Frame entirely off the screen.  I'm not entirely sure of the details here, but I suspect that this means that the Frame cannot be mapped, and therefore is not eligible to receive focus.

Comment: @jasonharper ah right. If your prediction is right, it should work for height as well, no? Even when I set the height to 10000 as long as the width is within bounds it works.

Comment: @jasonharper oops sorry the other way around, even if I set the width to 10000 as long as the height is within bounds it works.

Comment: @jasonharper ah I just tested it, you are correct. After making the canvas the child of the frame, it works. Thanks!